# Length between nested lists in beamer

Tags: beamer, spacing, lists

How do I adjust the length between nested lists?  For example, in the following, I would like to adjust the distance where it states "distance here"

```
\begin{itemize}
    \item one
    %% distance here
    \begin{itemize}
         \item
    \end{itemize}
    %% distance here
    \item two
\end{itemize}
```

UPDATE: I forgot to mention I am using `beamer`, and it appears traditional methods can go wrong in `beamer`, as `frame` defines its own definition of `itemize`.

Comment: You can use `\begin{itemize}\addtolength{\itemsep}{-0.5\baselineskip}`. See [this link about tweaklist](http://dcwww.camd.dtu.dk/~schiotz/comp/LatexTips/LatexTips.html#tweaklist) for more options.

Comment: @Peter Grill: but changing `\itemsep` will affect the vertical spacing between items, and Vinh Nguyen (if I understand the question correctly) needs to increase the vertical spacing before the first and after last items of the inner `itemize`.

Comment: This would help: [Is there a picture showing all the lengths used in lists?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17957)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You shouldn't use `enumitem` with `beamer`. This will probably break all the `beamer` settings for lists (e.g. overlays, alerts etc). Use either simply `vspace` (for a local solution) or the responsible `beamer` template. And next time show a complete example instead of a code snippet. The class is a crucial information.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

\begin{itemize}
        \item one
        %% distance here
        \begin{itemize}
             \item
        \end{itemize}
        %% distance here
        \item two
    \end{itemize}

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}

\begin{itemize}
        \item one
        \vspace{1cm}
        \begin{itemize}
             \item
        \end{itemize}
        \vspace{1cm}
        \item two
    \end{itemize}

\end{frame}


\begin{frame}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize/enumerate subbody begin}{\vspace{1cm}}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize/enumerate subbody end}{\vspace{1cm}}
\begin{itemize}
        \item one
        %% distance here
        \begin{itemize}
             \item
        \end{itemize}
        %% distance here
        \item two
    \end{itemize}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks!  I used placed the setbeamertemplate commands in the preamble so that its effects are global in the document.

Answer (score 6):

The vertical space that you want to modify is given by the sum of the lengths `\topsep`, and `\parskip`; the [`enumitem`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) package offers you a simple mechanism to control these (and some other attributes) of the list-like environments:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
        \item one
        \begin{itemize}[topsep=20pt]
             \item
        \end{itemize}
        \item two
    \end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

If you want to suppress all the vertical spacing in a list you can say something like

```
\usepackage{enumitem}
...
\begin{itemize}[nolistsep]
  \item
\end{itemize}
```

EDIT: an example with `beamer`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
Normal spacing
\begin{itemize}
        \item one
        \begin{itemize}
             \item First subitem
             \item Second subitem
        \end{itemize}
        \item two
    \end{itemize}
Increased spacing
\begin{itemize}
        \item one
        \begin{itemize}[topsep=20pt]
             \item First subitem
             \item Second subitem
        \end{itemize}
        \item two
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

However, using `enumitem` with `beamer` is *not* the best choice. See Ulrike's answer for a proper solution with `beamer`.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I'm doing this in Beamer, and enumitem does not work there (I don't see bullets).  Also, as seen [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16793/global-setting-of-spacing-between-items-in-itemize-environment-for-beamer), the frame environment has its own definition of itemize.  What to do...

Comment: @Vinh Nguyen: yes, you forgot crucial information. Can you please add to your question that you are using `beamer`?

Comment: @Vinh Nguyen: in fact, I just tested my example code using beamer instead of article and my code works (see my updated answer in a few minutes). If it is not working for you, please add a [minimal working example](http://www.minimalbeispiel.de/mini-en.html) illustrating your problem.

Comment: @Gonzalo Medina Thank you for your help.  Your working example is fine.  Although the spacing does seem to work, as mentioned in my comments, the bullets disappear (try without enumitem).  I would like to preserve the bullets in the lists.  Thank you so much.

Comment: @Vihn Nguyen: see Ulrike's answer for a proper solution with `beamer`.

Comment: @Gonzalo: Your image has been lost accidently by imgur.com

Answer (score 4):

Ulrike's solution for a global change isn't working for me.  Putting these lines

```
\setbeamertemplate{itemize/enumerate subbody begin}{\vspace{1cm}}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize/enumerate subbody end}{\vspace{1cm}}
```

either within a `frame` or in the preamble is doing nothing.  (I can provide details about my configuration, file, etc., but not sure what's relevant.)  In any event, I have found other (almost complete) solutions, although not as ... beamerly.

Solution 1: Put this in the preamble:

```
% space between items:
\newlength{\wideitemsep}
\setlength{\wideitemsep}{\itemsep}\addtolength{\wideitemsep}{3pt}
% reconfigure itemize lists:
\let\olditem\item
\renewcommand{\item}{%
\setlength{\itemsep}{\wideitemsep}%
\olditem}
```

Drawback (or advantage): Although the items are farther apart, lines of text before an after the list are still very close.
(I found this idea at http://blog.nguyenvq.com/2011/05/01/spacing-between-items-in-itemize-or-enumerate-environments-lists/.)

Solution 2: Almost the same thing, but this also adds space before the list:

```
\let\olditem\item
\renewcommand{\item}{%
\olditem\vspace{4pt}}
```

However, it does not add space after the list.  I'd like to find a global way to do that.  I've experimented with some of the other list parameters without success using this sort of method, which makes sense: The only effect you can have by redefining `\item` will be local to a particular item, in general.

Comment: If you indent your code with four spaces, it'll be put into a code block. There is also a button that looks like `{}` in the editor which will do this to selected text when you click on it.

Comment: Thanks Mark.  I am indeed new here.  I actually tried both!  It didn't seem to work either way.  Don't know why.  (Maybe because I used both four spaces and {}?) I'm glad Werner edited it.