# global vertical space of items & subitems in beamer

Tags: beamer, spacing, lists, itemize

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [length between nested lists](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20654/length-between-nested-lists)

> **Possible duplicate:**
>
> [Length between nested lists in beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/20654)

In order to better distinguish groups of notions, I'd like to be able to control the vertical space between items of `itemize` when subitems are also used as follows:

```
\begin{itemize}
\item level 1 a
\begin{itemize}
\item level 2 a 
\item level 2 b 
\end{itemize}\vspace*{2mm}
\item level 1 b
\end{itemize}
```

How to automatically set-up a 2mm vertical space when subitems are used and nothing otherwise?

Comment: See Ulrike Fischer's answer to this question: [length between nested lists](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/20654/3954).

Comment: yes, potentially a duplicate.