# Remove indentation on description list

Tags: lists, indentation, enumitem

Ok, I looked at [some](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119638/no-indent-in-description-list) [answers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/91124/itemize-removing-natural-indent), and they suggest to use the package enumitem and the option `[leftmargin=*]`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
  \section{Foo}
    \subsection{Bar}
      \subsection{Foobar}
        \paragraph{Fubar}
          \begin{description}[leftmargin=*]
            \item[First Item] The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            \item[Second Item] The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
          \end{description}
\end{document}
```

But this does not completely remove the indentation. Here's the result (notice the space before "fox").

[image]

On the other hand, `leftmargin=0cm` works, but I'm afraid it's not the same thing.

If the whole list is indented, I want the wrapped text to indent under at the start of the label, not at the left margin of the page.

I'm using a fresh installation of the latest MikTex (21 Oct 2014) x64, together with the latest TexStudio (2.8.6) on Windows 7 SP1 x64.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! What do you mean by "it's not the same thing?". You should adapt your example code in order to show a situation where your whole list is indented.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi I'm not sure it's the same thing, it's just something I tried. I'm sure you can find/encounter a situation where the whole list is indented.

Comment: `leftmargin=0cm` *is* the answer

Comment: As far as I know, the `\leftmargin` dimension is always relative to an existing indentation

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Thanks, I'd upvote your comment if I had the rep

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use `\leftmargin=0pt` to shift the indentation to the left boundary, this works in multiply nested lists.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
  \section{Foo}
    \subsection{Bar}
      \subsection{Foobar}
        \paragraph{Fubar}
        \begin{itemize}
          \item
          \begin{description}[leftmargin=0pt]
            \item[First Item] The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            \item[Second Item] The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
          \end{description}
          \end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: you don't need environment `itemize`, nor that extra `\item`. It's enough to replace `[leftmargin=*]` with `[leftmargin=0pt]`.

Comment: @RicoRally: It was just an example to show that the text of the inner list is aligned correctly nevertheless!

Comment: Upvoting, anyway. :)
I thought it could be even more useful.

Comment: BTW any idea why the paragraph "bold" looks smaller than the bold of the description items?

Comment: @Agostino: I should have a look on the standard `paragraph` fontsize...

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I haven't set it, anything I should add to the code to make it work better? Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You can also use `[wide=0\parindent]`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
  \section{Foo}
    \subsection{Bar}
      \subsection{Foobar}
        \paragraph{Fubar}
          \begin{description}[wide=0\parindent]
            \item[First Item] The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
            \item[Second Item] The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
          \end{description}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What's the difference?

Comment: @Agostino It is another method. Take it that way.

Comment: I know this is an old thread, but for me this one worked better, since @user31729's approach sent the text past my document-wide margins. This one just filled out the text up until the document margins, without adding more for the list.