# Issue with row spacing in tabular environement

Tags: tables, line-spacing

I have the following macro to format all my table together inside of my CV.

```
\documentclass[a4]{article}
\usepackage[left=1.5cm,top=2cm,right=1.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,nohead,nofoot]{geometry}

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
\newenvironment{entrylist}{%
  \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}ll}
}{%
  \end{tabular*}}

\renewcommand{\bfseries}{}
\newcommand{\entryacquis}[5]{%
  #1&\parbox[t]{14.5cm}{%
    \textbf{#2}%
    \hfill%
    {\footnotesize #3}\\%
    #4}\\
{Skills~:} &#5} 

\begin{document}

\begin{entrylist}
\entryacquis
{6\thinspace --\thinspace 8.2008}
{Job Position}
{A company}
{Job description}
{Some learned skills}
\end{entrylist}

\end{document}
```

The produced result :
  [image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/E7qD5.png]

How can I make the line spacing between the job description row and the skills row the same as between two normal text line ? That on is for some reason smaller.

I already tried to add `\baselineskip`, `\linebreak`, `\vspace` but I didn't get it to work properly.

Comment: Try `#4}\\[16pt]` in your command definition...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add some `\strut`s around your data (I did to both ends, in case the data spans more than a line).

```
\documentclass[a4]{article}
\usepackage[left=1.5cm,top=2cm,right=1.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,nohead,nofoot]{geometry}

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
\newenvironment{entrylist}{%
  \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}ll}
}{%
  \end{tabular*}}

\renewcommand{\bfseries}{}
\newcommand{\entryacquis}[5]{%
  #1&\parbox[t]{14.5cm}{%
    \strut\textbf{#2}%
    \hfill%
    {\footnotesize #3}\\%
    #4\strut}\\
{Skills~:} &\strut#5\strut} 

\begin{document}

\begin{entrylist}
\entryacquis
{6\thinspace --\thinspace 8.2008}
{Job Position}
{A company}
{Job description}
{Some learned skills}
\end{entrylist}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help. Now it works correctly for simple case but if I end my job description by Itemize, I got an empty line in between. Any idea how I can fix it ?

Comment: @Pierrick I think that is really a separate question about how to eliminate extra vertical space associated with `itemize`.  I know such questions have been asked on this site. You can search, and I will too.  If I find a relevant question, I will let you know.

Comment: @Pierrick You may find this relevant, in that it shows where those extra spaces come from: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17957/is-there-a-picture-showing-all-the-lengths-used-in-lists

Comment: I just came to the same conclusion after playing around with `itemize` and `strut`. Thanks you for the confirmation, I will search for the `itemize` variable.

Comment: with the answer you point me out, I was able to delete the spacing after `itemize` outside of the `tabular` environment. But when I have `itemize` inside of my tabular, I didn't found any way to remove it. Any suggestion how to do it? Or should I post a new question and related it to this one ?