# How to control vertical spacing before and after Itemize within the tabular environment?

Tags: tables, itemize

After asking [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/312682/issue-with-row-spacing-in-tabular-environement) about how to add some spacing between two row in a tabular environment, I figured out some strange behaviour of the `itemize` command within the `tabular*` environment.

Using the solution suggested by [Steven B. Segletes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/25858/steven-b-segletes) leads me to another one. When I use the `itemize` command inside of my `tabular*` environment I am not able to remove the vertical spacing after it if it is at the very end of the cell. If it is some text before and after it is fine.

My MWE to illustrate my issue

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[left=1.5cm,top=2cm,right=1.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,nohead,nofoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist{nosep}

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
\newenvironment{entrylist}{%
  \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}ll}
}{%
  \end{tabular*}}

\renewcommand{\bfseries}{}
\newcommand{\entryacquis}[5]{%
  #1&\parbox[t]{14.5cm}{%
    \textbf{#2}%
    \hfill%
    #3\\%
    #4\strut}\\
{Skills~:} &#5} 

\begin{document}

\begin{entrylist}
\entryacquis
{6\thinspace --\thinspace 8.2008}
{Job Position}
{A company}
{something}
{Some learned skills}
\end{entrylist}
\vspace{40pt}

\begin{entrylist}
\entryacquis
{6\thinspace --\thinspace 8.2008}
{Job Position}
{A company}
{\begin{itemize}
\item Something
\end{itemize}}
{Some learned skills}
\end{entrylist}
\vspace{40pt}

\begin{entrylist}
\entryacquis
{6\thinspace --\thinspace 8.2008}
{Job Position}
{A company}
{text
\begin{itemize}
\item Something
\end{itemize}
text}
{Some learned skills}
\end{entrylist}

\end{document}
```

And the output it produce :

[image]

Can somebody help me to figure out how to have the same spacing as in the first table with a list of item at the very bottom of my table's cell ?

Comment: Within the right margin of this page, see all the "Related" posts. There's a combination that should work for you.

Comment: @Werner I already checked them all and many others. But I was not able to find out how to achieve what I want in my case. I also tried to put the `itemize` of a `minipage` but didn't work neither.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just play with the `before` and `after` keys for itemize:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[hmargin=1.5cm,top=2cm,bottom=2.5cm,noheadfoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist{nosep}

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
\newenvironment{entrylist}{%
  \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}ll}
}{%
  \end{tabular*}}

\renewcommand{\bfseries}{}
\newcommand{\entryacquis}[5]{%
  #1&\parbox[t]{14.5cm}{%
    \textbf{#2}%
    \hfill%
    #3\\%
    #4\strut}\\
{Skills~:} &#5}

\begin{document}

\begin{entrylist}
\entryacquis
{6\thinspace --\thinspace 8.2008}
{Job Position}
{A company}
{something}
{Some learned skills}
\end{entrylist}
\vspace{40pt}

\begin{entrylist}
\entryacquis
{6\thinspace --\thinspace 8.2008}
{Job Position}
{A company}
{\begin{itemize}[before=\vspace*{-\baselineskip}, after=\vspace*{-\baselineskip}]
\item Something
\end{itemize}}
{Some learned skills}
\end{entrylist}
\vspace{40pt}

\begin{entrylist}
\entryacquis
{6\thinspace --\thinspace 8.2008}
{Job Position}
{A company}
{text
\begin{itemize}
\item Something
\end{itemize}
text}
{Some learned skills}
\end{entrylist}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great ! That does what I want ! Can I also implement this in the preambule so it make the same things for all the itemize used in my document ?

Comment: I'm afraid if there's text before or after, it won't fit nicely. I suggest your define your own personal itemize, with these parameters (`\setlist{myitemize}{…}`), and use this personal itemize when there is no text.

Comment: Yes you are right, if there is text before or after, then Both lines overlap each other. But it does the tricks for the moment. I will continue to search for another solution to implement it at the beginning.