# exam: How to add a vertical skip to the question head and remove its body indentation?

Tags: indentation, exam, vspace

For the following MWE,

```
\documentclass[addpoints]{exam}

\begin{document}
    \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
    \qformat{\textbf{\underline{Question (\thequestion) [\totalpoints\ Marks]}}\hfill}

    \begin{questions}
        \question[15]
        \vspace{\baselineskip}% doesn't increase the spacing between the head and body
        question body
    \end{questions}
\end{document}
```

how can I:

1- increase the spacing between the question head and its body (in addition to understanding why `vspace` doesn't work as expected)

2- and left-align the question body with its head?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is:

```
\documentclass[addpoints]{exam}

% Remove margins
\renewcommand{\questionshook}{%
  \setlength{\leftmargin}{0pt}%
  \setlength{\labelwidth}{-\labelsep}%
}

\begin{document}
    %\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
    \qformat{\textbf{\underline{Question (\thequestion) [\totalpoints\ Marks]}}\hfill}

    \begin{questions}
        \question[15] \hspace*{0pt}\vspace*{\baselineskip}

        question body

        \question[10] \hspace*{0pt}\vspace*{\baselineskip}

        question body

    \end{questions}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you please explain to me the meaning of the preamble? I don't quite understand `\leftmargin`, `\labelwidth` and `\labelsep`. Or you can refer me that part of the manual where I can find some explanation about them.

Comment: The `questions` environment is nothing more than a list, like `itemize`. Covered deep in the `exam` class, `\question` is merely an `\item`, so the normal list paramaters apply. You can find the list parameters at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17957/is-there-a-picture-showing-all-the-lengths-used-in-lists

Comment: May I know what macro is used for recalling the value of `\labelwidth`, `\labelsep` for either questions or labels?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. `\labelwidth` et al. gives you the values.